# Any way to replicate the .Net Core DeflateStream.Flush() behaviour in .Net Framework?

Tags: c#, deflatestream

### Background

I want to use [StreamJsonRpc](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-streamjsonrpc/blob/main/doc/overview.md) as a replacement for WCF in a future .Net Core port of an application. Before porting the code to .Net Core, I want to update the existing code (which is .Net Framework 4.8) to use StreamJsonRpc.

Because the data written by StreamJsonRpc is large compared to the binary source data, and is extremely compressible, I want to use [`DeflateStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream?view=net-5.0) to compress it.

This leads on to the problem: **The compression works with .Net Core, but it doesn't work with .Net Framework.**

### Why it doesn't work

Consider the following code:

```
var output   = new MemoryStream();
var deflater = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen:true);
var data     = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is the data to be compressed");

deflater.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
deflater.Flush();

Console.WriteLine(output.Length); // 0 for .Net 4.8, >0 for .Net Core 3.1+
```

For .Net Core, this outputs a number greater than zero. For .Net Framework, this outputs zero.

I've instrumented `StreamJsonRpc` and I can see that it is calling `Stream.Flush()` after it writes a block of data, so I'm fairly sure that this is the problem.

The .Net Core implementation of `DeflateStream.Flush()` actually does flush, but the .Net Framework implementation does nothing.

### My Question

Is there any way in .Net Framework 4.8 to flush a `DeflateStream`? If there is, I can write a wrapper class for `DeflateStream` that implements `Stream.Flush()` so that it actually flushes.

### Other Notes

[A bug was raised for this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15371) in October 2015, and [it was fixed for .Net Core](https://github.com/ianhays/corefx/commit/a399fca70c747f31b204e8bfeaec8eaf53b124a0) in December 2015.

Also, [the documentation for `DeflateStream.Flush()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream.flush?view=net-5.0) is incorrect.

For .Net Framework *and* .Net Core the header says:

> The current implementation of this method has no functionality.

But under *Remarks* it says:

> Flushes the internal buffer if the compression mode is set to Compress.

Clearly both those things can't be true, and the documentation should be different for .Net Core versus .Net Framework.

Comment: You must Dispose() the DeflateStream. No need to Flush(), Dispose() does implicit flush. Edit: the docs also says:  Flush() The current implementation of this method has no functionality. It says this for all versions of .NET. So the question is: how can this possibly work in .Net Core 3.1

Comment: I tested in .NET Core 3.1 and it actually works. So this seems to be a bug in .NET Core 3.1 docs not updated. In any case I would never rely on Flush() actually doing something, it will make the code not portable to older .NET versions. I  think fixing this "bug" may have been a mistake.

Comment: BTW: here is the one I am using in .net 4.8 (compression added). It is modified from the previous release before the MessagePack bug fix, but that's fine for me as I am not using MP. This class must be copied into your own code:  https://github.com/gdalsnes/vs-streamjsonrpc/blob/master/src/StreamJsonRpc/WebSocketMessageHandlerGZip.cs

Comment: Not sure why I used GZip instead of Deflate, but might have been paranoid and inspired by gzip being most commonly used with http. In any case its an easy swap.

Comment: @osexpert It is the code in the StreamJsonRPC implementation that calls `Flush()` so I have no control over that. I just put it in my repro code to show how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right that .NET framework is simply buggy. Of course flush should cause all data written so-far to be emitted. Yes, this decreases compression ratio, but not upholding the conventions around flush is much worse.